# Using EventKit with swift on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I'm trying to get a list of all events from iCal for this week with swift. 
I would like to see how many Events there are and what categories they belong to. 
How can this be done programatically. 
Is Eventkit the right choice or should AppleScript be used? Is there a tutorial for Eventkit with swift? I could not find one.

Comment: you could try to do this with the EKEventStore which is in EventKit there is a function `predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:` wich returns a predicate for a Date which you can use with `enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:usingBlock:` to get all events in a 7 day span

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following singleton to access the `EventStore`

```
private let _SingletonSharedInstance = EventStore()

class EventStore {
  let eventStore = EKEventStore ()

  class var sharedInstance : EventStore {
    return _SingletonSharedInstance
  }

  init() {
    var sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var hasAccess = false

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: { (granted:Bool, error:NSError?) in hasAccess = granted; dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema) })

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    if (!hasAccess) {
      alert ("ACCESS", "ACCESS LONG")
      let sharedWorkspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
      sharedWorkspace.openFile("/Applications/System Preferences.app")
      exit (0)
    }
  }
}
```

*Note*: `alert` is one of my private methods to create an alert. Replace it as needed.

To access the eventstore in my app I use

```
let eventStore = EventStore.sharedInstance.eventStore
...
for et in eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) {
   // check calendars
}
```

The docu about then event store is quite complete so you can probably make your way from here.

Comment: Thanks for this very good explanation. I think i will find my way from here.