# Calendar with selectable range of dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, calendar

I'm searching for a library that provodes a calendar that allows me to select single dates and whole ranges of dates that I can use on my app.

Is there any iOS library that provide such features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EKEventStore` it allows a lot of calendar access including selection of specific date ranges. I posted some sample here: [Using EventKit with swift on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412517/using-eventkit-with-swift-on-osx/29412721#29412721)